# Reload Java Fx Scene?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I want to reload my Scene of the Java Fx project.

So i created a button, which has an Fx-ID

now i want to create something, that reloads the whole fx scene after pressing the button...

How is this possible.?

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
    stage.setTitle("!");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage
```

this is my scene

Comment: Just load it again, and set the root of the scene. What's the specific problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
Stage close = (Stage) restart.getScene().getWindow();
    close.close();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
    stage.setTitle("!");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

this should help to close your stage. you will also create another stage, with deleted inputs

Comment: Why create a new `Scene` and new `Stage`?

Comment: i tried to close the old scene and create a new one at the same time, which is the new scene to play a game for a example.

Comment: Why though? Why not just reuse the existing ones?

Comment: that true, also possible... thank you

Comment: I seriously don’t understand why the OP thinks this answer is correct. What is wrong with `FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(…);` and `restart.getScene().setRoot(fxmlLoader.load());`. Nowhere does the question say anything about creating new windows.